# Python CSV module with unix dialect writes different tab character when using QUOTE_NONE

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a tab-delimited csv file on Windows but want it to be a Linux-friendly format. However, the values should not be quoted. When I use the csv module with the below options, the tab appears as taking only a single space in the output.

```
with open('myFile.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', dialect='unix', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(myData)
```

[output with QUOTE_NONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFlDP.png) (screenshot from Notepad++)

If I remove QUOTE_NONE, the tab character displays as the right size, but then the file has quoted values, which I don't want.

```
with open('myFile.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', dialect='unix')
    writer.writerows(myData)
```

[output with quotes left on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDK8P.png)

What's going on here?

Comment: I think that's still a normal tab in your first example. Tabs aren't always the same size, they adapt their size to line up with fixed positions. Try writing multiple rows with values of various lengths in place of `stringdatum`.

Comment: Also, try viewing your file in hex editor where you can see the byte values. Tab characters will show up as \x09.  See http://www.asciitable.com/  for more information

Comment: Thanks, they seem to be the same character. I guess it isn't a big issue.